# How to handle with dynamic approach with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to do a dynamic integration with regular expressions.

I am trying to find the subset of zeros from the string. To find the single zeros and double zero existence. my code works. but I am duplicating the code as 2 time.

Here it is:

```js
const str = '0000';

const count1 = /0{1}/;
const reg1 = new RegExp(count1, 'g');
const match1 = str.match(reg1);
console.log(match1);

const count2 = /0{2}/;
const reg2 = new RegExp(count2, 'g');
const match2 = str.match(reg2);
console.log(match2);
```

But how do I avoid this duplication, by dynamically updating `count` and `count2` something like this:

```
for(i=1;i<=2;i++){
const count1 = /0{i}/; //here is the dynamic update
const reg1 = new RegExp(count1, 'g');
const match1 = str.match(reg1);
console.log(match1);
}
```

Or how to handle this kind of scenario?

Comment: Write a method that encapsulates it? The *best* answer depends on what you're doing with the result. If it's something like "if it starts with four zeros it's a foo" just use `startsWith` and build up something useful on the business side with that--it's easy enough to change, but super clear when reading if you're not using a lot of regex power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp) takes a `RegExp` object or a string, and convert it to a new `RegExp` object. Instead of `count` being a `RegExp`, convert it to a string with the dynamic value, and then convert it to a `RegExp` using the constructor:

```js
const str = '0000';

for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  const count = `0{${i}}`; //here is the dynamic update
  const reg = new RegExp(count, 'g');
  const match = str.match(reg);
  console.log(match);
}
```

As suggested by [Dave Newton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75770222/how-to-handle-with-dynamic-approach-with-regexp/75770296#comment133661312_75770222) you can create a reusable function:

```js
const str = '0000';

const matchZeroes = (str, len) => str.match(new RegExp(`0{${len}}`, 'g'));

console.log(matchZeroes(str, 1));
console.log(matchZeroes(str, 2));
```